# How to compare given value with Pandas dataframe values without using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example dataframe:

```
d = {'target': [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output:

```
    target
0   1
1   2
2   4
3   3
4   6
5   5
```

I need a function that will do the following:

Let the function have the name `find_index_of_first_hit(value)`.

The function...

- will be comparing the function input `value` with elements of the column `target`.
- will search for the first column value that is greater than or equal to the function input `value`.
- and will return the **`index`** of the dataframe row for the very first match.

Example:

```
find_index_of_first_hit(3)
```

Should return `2` which is the index of the `target` column value 4, which is where the column value (which is 4) is >= the function input value 3 for the first time in the column. And the index is 2, which is expected to be returned.

- The function is expected to return -1 if none of column values are >= the function input value.

The original dataframe is fairly large and I wonder how I can write such a program without using for loop.

This function needs to be written in Python and it needs to be a fast solution, which is why I would like to avoid for loop. Performance is important here.

How can I write such a Python function doing this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with test if value exist in `if-else` with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
def find_index_of_first_hit(val):
    a = df['target'].ge(val)
    return a.idxmax() if a.any() else -1

print (find_index_of_first_hit(3))
2
print (find_index_of_first_hit(30))
-1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It covers even returning -1.

Answer (score 1):

use an equality check `.eq` with [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

You'll find you rarely need to write any functions for Pandas (unless you need to package up reusable code snippets) as most things are available in the API.

```
index = df.ge(3).idxmax()

target    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I needed the function that also returns -1 when there is no hit. jezrael's answer covers that as well.

Comment: no worries @edn :) good luck in your code.